# minimizing waiting time for 8051 port state

Tags: microcontroller, resistors, data, 8051, speed

I made myself a project with standard 8051 microcontrollers (AT89S52 and AT89C4051) and will be making more with the same due to price and availability.

When data is being sent from one GPIO pin from one microcontroller to another on the same circuit board with short traces, How long exactly would it take for the other microcontroller to receive the data?

And, even though at least one microcontroller's GPIO pin has at least an internal pullup resistor in the chip, would adding a small valued external pull-up reduce the time it takes for the other microcontroller to receive the data? If so, just how low could I go before that section prevents the rest of the circuitry from working?

I was thinking 1K as the lowest to be safe? but I definitely wouldn't want to go under 100 ohms because I might fry the internal microcontroller circuitry the pin is attached to.

For both microcontrollers, I'm using 22.1184Mhz crystals each with 2 33pF 5% NPO capacitors, and the trace length from the micro to crystal connection point is 1cm max, and both are powered with regulated 5 VDC.

Comment: What kind of communication protocol are you using? Serial or Parallel? Asynchronous or Synchronous?

Comment: Why do you reason on transmission times of signals in the nanosecond range if the code to read them will be in the microsecond range?

Comment: what do you mean by `receive data`?

Comment: Microcontrollers are *synchronous machines*. GPIO inputs are clocked in synchronously, likely no faster than one machine cycle...which is usually a sub-multiple of the crystal clock. So a lower-value  pullup won't help. If your GPIO pin is mapped to a serial peripheral device (like I2C), then that device might have *asynchronous inputs*...now a lower-value pullup might make a difference.

Comment: Parallel based. I'm using a port as bi-directional and a GPIO pin from another port as a clock. The reason why I'm on about pull-ups is because I believe that can affect response speed

Answer (score 1):

> When data is being sent from one GPIO pin from one microcontroller to
>   another on the same circuit board with short traces, How long exactly
>   would it take for the other microcontroller to receive the data?

The time taken for the signal to travel down the wire will be minuscule compared to the time taken for the other MCU to respond to it. The AT89C4051 takes a minimum of 12 clock cycles per instruction. Since the data will be arriving asynchronously the average latency will be even longer. With a 22.1184MHz clock the CPU instruction cycle time is ~540ns, so a signal rise time longer than that *may* start to become noticeable. However in practice you probably need several instructions to read and process the signal, so a slower rise time may still be acceptable.

Assuming a total capacitance of 50pF or less, a 10K resistor should give a rise time of ~250ns, less than 1/2 a CPU cycle. The internal pullups (on ports that have them) are equivalent to a 50~100k resistor, so rise time could be as slow as 2.5us. Depending on how fast your code can respond to the signal that still might be OK.

Comment: `However in practice you probably need several instructions to read and process the signal`... That's the problem. I don't want to execute too many instructions. I mean if I was ok with slowness, I'd execute `mov A,PORT, nop, nop .... nop,` then act on accumulator, but I want to eliminate those nops. I read somewhere that too low of value for pull-up resistors may create noise in the circuit, but just how low could I go?

Comment: Also I noticed that for pin capacitance of the AT89C4051 according to datasheet is 10pF maximum if the operating frequency is 1Mhz and temperature is 25 degrees but I'm running it at 22.1184Mhz. How do I calculate the actual capacitance?

Comment: _" I don't want to execute too many instructions"_ Reading the port only takes one instruction, but if that was all you did it wouldn't be much use. At a minimum you will want to store the data somewhere or branch depending on the pin state, and this _will_ require several instructions. This is one reason why dedicated peripherals such as SPI are often preferred for communication (they take up fewer pins and in practice are about the same speed). With a 10k pullup the signal will rise in less than 1 CPU cycle which is practically zero time from the MCU's perspective.

Comment: Operating frequency makes no difference to the capacitance value. You aren't using the port capacitance as part of a tuned circuit, and the rise time of your signal just has to be fast _enough_,  so the exact value doesn't matter. For my calculations I added the capacitance of both pins (send/receive) and generously added another 30pF to account for possible IC sockets and wiring etc., In practice it will probably be less than this, so you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: The capacitors in the crystal circuit are another matter. So long as it oscillates they should be fine. If you need an exact frequency (eg. for an accurate time of day clock) then you may need a trimmer capacitor to tune the crystal.